# Get the number of degrees the div is on in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a circle and I need to know the level of a particular div. For example, I have divided a circle here into 4 pieces. My goal is to find out how many degrees the circled div is at. This so that I can change the color of the background. So for example when a div is between 0 and 90 degrees, the background color should be blue, and from 90 to 180 degrees green. Can this be calculated with javascript?
[image]

I myself had already experimented to calculate the difference between the points with the x position and the y position of an object, but unfortunately without success. that looked like this:

```
  handleDrag = (e, ui) => {

    var p1 = {
      x: ui.x,
      y: ui.y
    };
    
    var p2 = {
      x: ui.x,
      y: ui.y
    };
    
    // angle in radians
    var angleRadians = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
    
    // angle in degrees
    var angleDeg = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;

    console.log("graden:"+angleDeg);
}
```

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: You don't need to know degrees, you need to know where is your center placed in the screen, let's say it is in the (500,500), then you only need to know where the box is placed, if the left > 500 and bottom > 500 you know it is in the top right, and so on

Comment: Sorry for other things it is also very important that I know the amount of degrees a div is placed on. I just can't get away with the position.

Comment: The approach seems correct. Please create a [mcve] either here in stack snippet or in jsfiddle. It will help to debug easier.

Comment: I have one project which calculates the degrees between positions with similar approach. If your circle center has some coordinates you could use those with:```var diffx = this.target.x-this.x;var diffy = this.target.y-this.y;var radians = Math.atan2(diffy, diffx);var degrees = 180 * radians / Math.PI;```

Comment: Then with degrees you can just do: `if(degrees >= 0 && degrees <= 90 ){//bg blue`

Comment: So use the object centers for those if you want it to be accurate. ie circle center coordinates and object center coordinates: `var objectCenter.x = this.x+(this.width/2); var objectCenter.y = this.y + (this.height/2);`

Comment: Also note that this method returns degrees between -180 to 180. 0 degrees is at right.

Comment: So the top-right degrees are 0 to 90, bottom-right degrees are 0 to -90

Comment: Thanks for your response, but what do i need to fill in at this.target.x -this.x and  this.target.y -this.y, with ui.x and ui.y i got the position of the div but i can't match it with your code